# ASP.NET WebForm Web API Token authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I am able to add Web API in my existing Web Form website project using approach given at http://www.kashyapas.com/2013/05/16/web-api-in-asp-net-web-forms-application/

Now I want to add token based authentication for my API. Please help me to add it?

Mainly client will pass username and password. After authentication for all further requests client should pass toke to access information.

Thank you

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck? If you don't know where to start, google OWIN and JWT. Setup one area/route for username/password based authentication, and use jwt for the rest of the api like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808964/mvc-with-owin-jwt-identity

Comment: After successful authentication you can set a cookie with HttpOnly set to true on the outgoing response. On all sub-subsequent requests the cookie will comeback in the Request and you can extract the value out of it and compare/validate against the logged in user.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will it work for all systems that are going to consume the API?